# which timer to use for windows service that does polling at specified interval without multithreading

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I am in the process of developing a `C#` `windows service` that polls multiple databases sequentially at specified intervals(15mins). I am not using multithreading because its a very heavy report generation process per database and there are other OLTP applications using the same databases on the same server, if we start multiple threads to deal with multiple databases simultaneously it will bring the server down.

I need to know which timer should be used `System.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`. Also when the interval is set to 15 mins and database processing has not completed and is taking more than 15 mins then interval 15 min should not execute until all the processing is complete.
Can anyone help please.

Comment: I'd just run a single new thread that keeps track of the time that it started, does its tasks, adds 15 minutes on to the stored time, and sleeps if the new calculated time hasn't been reached yet.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever could u post some sample code if possible as i have not used threading before

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Timers.Timer

and in your event to handle the ticking of the timer, disable the timer whilst processing is happening. Then re-enable it once you have completed your work. This will guard against calling your business logic again whilst your are processing.

```
private void TimerEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        _serviceTimer.Enabled = false;
        DoWork();
        _serviceTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: The OP wants their code to run every 15 minutes. But they're concerned that `DoWork()` may, itself, take over 15 minutes, so we can reasonably conclude that it can easily take multiple minutes. The issue with the above is that it waits 15 minutes *between* each timer firing event - so if `DoWork` typically takes 10 minutes, the above will effectively be running it every 25 minutes, not every 15 minutes.

Comment: Yes I see,  valid point. Your comment is the more correct answer in that case.